# XSD does not return fault with DOMDocument

Tags: php, xml, xsd, domdocument, xsd-validation

I'm trying to validate an XML file with an XSD in PHP with `DOMDocument`.
The `translation` element must not appear in my XML but `schemaValidate` does not return an error. I tested with the validation with another validation tool and it returns an error. I don't understand why `schemaValidate` validates a bad XML.

a part of XSD

```
<xs:complexType name="CV">
  <xs:complexContent>
     <xs:restriction base="CE">
        <xs:sequence>
           <xs:element name="originalText" type="ED" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1">
              <xs:annotation>
                 <xs:documentation>
                    The text or phrase used as the basis for the coding.
                 </xs:documentation>
              </xs:annotation>
           </xs:element>
           <xs:element name="translation" type="CD" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
```

my XML

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CV><translation/></CV>
```

my code

```
$dom = new DOMDocument("1.0","UTF-8");
$dom->loadXML("<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>
<CV><translation></translation></CV>");
echo $dom->schemaValidate("TestClasses.xsd");
```

for the complete XSD
[TestClasses.xsd](http://pastebin.com/RDFk1snY)

Thank for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At first glance, this does look like a bug in the schema validator.  The [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.schemavalidate.php) suggests (but does not say explicitly) that schemaValidate() uses libxml.  And libxml's XSD support is not yet complete.

For what it's worth, I note that commenting out the line

```
<xs:element name="translation" type="CD" 
            minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="0"/>
```

allows libxml to produce the correct result here, without invalidating the schema (as far as I can tell from a quick test with Saxon and Xerces J).